# How easy is to checkout the plugins being used by a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I was going through a site and saw that site is developed in wordpress. However, when i land on below page. I am unable to understand whether they have used a wordpress plugin or api to develop functionality:

https://legaldesk.com/affidavits/affidavit-for-change-of-name

Above link shows me a form when I select any city and click on create agreement. It asks for my details and on the right it shows preview.

Please answer . If this question should not be asked here, please do let me know the right site on which I can ask this. I like learning new technologies.

Comment: Right click your page, select "view source" and search for "plugins" in the paths you find. One plugin used is http://codecanyon.net/item/mega-main-menu-wordpress-menu-plugin/6135125 MegaMainMenu also Woocommerce, LayerSlider http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246

Answer (score 1):

The forms themselves seem to be from "TemplatesForm" [sourceforge.net/projects/kobject/files/kobject-java/tests/tests/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kobject/files/kobject-java/tests/tests/phase2/P2-2-TEMPLATESFORM/)…

Generally, the process  of finding which plugins and scripts is one of a kind of forensic detection using, on the one hand, direct links to scripts' sources, which lead to the publisher's url and on the other, class names and other names or function calls, for example, found in the HTML.

Apart from obvious signs like "Powered by WordPress" or similar lines which some sites will have clearly displayed on them, you can find out a lot from the HTML page source.

Right click your page, select "view source" and search for, for example, "plugins" in the paths you find. One plugin used here is http://codecanyon.net/item/mega-main-menu-wordpress-menu-plugin/6135125 MegaMainMenu also Woocommerce, LayerSlider http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246 and FlexSlider https://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

In this case, this is the theme - http://themeforest.net/item/envor-fully-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/9251688

They are also using Visual composer WYSIWIG plugin to help build it. [codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/…](http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431)

You can launch scripts in browser windows as text by clicking on links to them in the HTML itself (at your own risk but it usually pops up in the browser as text)  and you will often find the licence agreement texts at the top of the script.

You can see what national language the script has traces of to establish nationality (for example the forms scripts have traces of French in their variable names, which match with those on this site) This will help to confirm if you have discovered a script which was produced in the country you expect.

You can also see what programming language is involved, to help in your search and understanding of how the site works.

Website traffic in this case is monitored by Data Sumo Me https://sumome.com/ and Google Analytics. Also the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin is used. The URLs and names here are fairly obvious in the page's HTML and in HTML comments.

The part that pops up the overlays [wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95661/… myModalLabel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95661/open-wordpress-posts-in-bootstrap-modal) is BootStrap Modal - More on Modal Popups from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal_plugin.htm which seemed a very clear tutorial and explained the application of modal popups well.

More on Modal dialogue boxes - there is plenty you can do with those and they have been used extensively on this site [en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/modal-dialog modal-dialog for popup dialog boxes](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/modal-dialog/) - you may find other bits on this site, including the usual jquery, bootstrap and fonts/css.

Another script called "imageareaselect [odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) is used for selecting image areas.

As this question is a little "off topic" for Stack Overflow you should probably try on Wordpress StackExchange, [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) though they don't actually recommend any specific plugins as a matter of policy. I am also not recommending any here, only answering your question as to what has been used here and hope that the focus on what actually makes it work will be of use and interest to programmers who read this answer.

I can't see any other ones indicated in your webpage example - there may be some I have not noticed, but this answer is also intended partly as an example of the forensic analysis processes involved in working out what powers a site, which is at least partly within the scope of StackOverflow and I hope you will be able to use it to help you complete the discovery of any I missed. This started out as a collection of comments but seemed to develop a life of its own.

Comment: Thanks Steve. This is really helpful

Comment: Glad to know that, thanks! Hope it will be useful for others too. The forms system looks as if it has quite a powerful interface for setting up new forms and functionality.